# How to represent the following system function in a block diagram?

Tags: discrete-signals

I am aware that this a simple question, but I haven't been able to find a single reference that explains this situation. The system function is:

$$\frac{1}{1-(0.3)(1+j)D}$$

How can one draw a block diagram with only real components to represent something that is complex?

The system function is

$$\frac{Y}{x}  = \frac{1}{1-(0.3)(1+j)D} \implies Y(1-(0.3)(1+j)D)=X$$
where $Y$ is the output and $X$ is the input.

Therefore $$Y-DY(0.3)(1+j)=X \implies y[n]=0.3y[n-1](1+j)+x[n]$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a simple first-order recursive system like this:

[image]

In your case $b[0]=1$, $b[1]=0$, and $a[1]=-0.3(1+j)$. Of course the coefficient is complex if your system is complex. What you can do is split the real and imaginary parts and get two real-valued systems. The output of one is the real part of the output signal $y[n]$, and the output of the other is the imaginary part:

$$y_R[n]=0.3y_R[n-1]-0.3y_I[n-1]+x_R[n]\\
y_I[n]=0.3y_R[n-1]+0.3y_I[n-1]+x_I[n]$$

where $y_R[n]$ and $y_I[n]$ are the real and imaginary parts of $y[n]$, respectively (and the same for $x[n]$). If the input signal is real-valued then of course $x_I[n]=0$.

As for general complex-valued systems also have a look at this figure from the textbook *Digital Communication* by Lee and Messerschmitt:

[image]

Comment: The system must use real components

Comment: Thanks for the update. How would you split it exactly? Would that mean that y has two outputs or is it simply the sum?

Comment: @user29568: I just added the equations to my answer. Please have a look. But yes, there must be two outputs because $y[n]$ is complex-valued.

Comment: How is the imaginary part of $y[n]$ dependent on the real part of $y[n-1]$

Comment: @user29568: Because you have a complex coefficient. Just take the real part and the imaginary part of the equation for $y[n]$, then it's pretty obvious.

Comment: isnt it $\mathfrak{Re}(y[n])= \mathfrak{Re}(0.3y[n-1](1+j)+x[n])=0.3y[n-1]+x[n]$

Comment: @user29568: Well, you forget that $y[n]$ is complex valued, so you get $0.3y_R[n-1]-0.3y_I[n-1]+x[n]$ (assuming for the moment that $x[n]$ is real-valued).

Comment: @user29568: You're welcome! In case you consider the answer satisfactory, please accept it (by clicking the check mark next to it) so other users can see that your problem has been solved.

Comment: I am curious, do you know any reference that has some useful information on real and complex signals in relation to block diagrams?

Comment: @user29568: Not really, but I added one figure I found in one of my books to my answer, hope it helps. But if you just need a block diagram for the system in your question, you basically just have two real-valued first-order systems the outputs of which are cross-connected to the adder (at the input of the delay) of the respective other system.